# (Win32) How to launch a dialog box?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to recreate the famous [Windows 93 Hydra virus](https://www.windows93.net/#!hydra) for Windows 95 using Microsoft Visual C++ 4.0, but due to my inexperience with `Win32` I'm having trouble launching the main dialog box.

Here is what I was able to come with so far (the rest of the code can be found in [this github repo](https://github.com/GarkGarcia/hydra)):

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

static HINSTANCE hInstanceGlobal;

BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND H, UINT M, WPARAM W, LPARAM L);

inline int CreateHead()
{
    return DialogBox(hInstanceGlobal,
                     MAKEINTRESOURCE(HYDRA),
                     0, DialogProc);
}

BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND H, UINT M, WPARAM W, LPARAM L)
{
    switch (M)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        CreateHead();
        CreateHead();
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return TRUE;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    hInstanceGlobal = hInstance;
    return CreateHead();
}
```

The program compiles, but when I run it does absolutely nothing.

What am I doing wrong? How could I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: You don't have a message loop, your program exits immediatly

Comment: @kar: That's incorrect. There *is* a message loop. And [DialogBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxw) *"does not return control until the specified callback function terminates the modal dialog box by calling the EndDialog function."*

Comment: The return value of `DialogProc()` is *indeterminate* when the dialog receives a `WM_COMMAND` message. And `DialogProc()` never calls `EndDialog()`

Comment: You're right, I forgot to call `EndDialog()`. I don't really get why the return value of `DialogProc` is indeterminate thought. Could you explain?